# Disabling file permissions on NFS share

Tags: permissions, nfs, file-permissions

I am trying to set up a nfs share for use by non-technical users, and really don't want file permissions messing things up. Everyone should be able to read/write anything on this share without even knowing what file permissions are, much less adjusting them.

Is there a way I can just make the nfs server write everything as 770 or something? It seems like this should be easy, but the best I can come up with is a cronjob to periodically set them to that, which is far from ideal.

The server is a Netgear ReadyNAS. Ideally I would like to stick to doing stuff from within the web interface on it, but I can just root it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution. One can use SGID to force the permissions of all new files/folders in a directory to be the same as that of the directory itself. More info at:

http://www.library.yale.edu/wsg/docs/permissions/sgid.htm